# .NET Core, Angular2, NancyFX - 404 changing URL in browser

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core, nancy

When serving the application with .NET Core static files I'm unable to change the URL in the browser. When doing so I'm given the

> 404 - Not Found

Nancy error page.

The only URL that's working is the base URL, localhost:5000. Changing the URL to localhost:5000/reservations gives me 404. Pressing F5 when not on the base URL will also result in a 404.

If I use the browsersync url, localhost:4200, everything works and I can change the URL and press F5 without 404. This is what I'm doing when developing but not when it's deployed on the server using IIS.

**Running the application in IIS Express**

1. ng build (files are copied over to wwwroot along with index.html)
2. start IIS Express

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        services.AddMvc();

        services.InjectServices();

        services.AddOptions();

        services.Configure<Endpoints>(Configuration.GetSection("Endpoints"));

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (!context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        });

        app.UseDefaultFiles();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        loggerFactory.AddNLog();

        app.AddNLogWeb();

        app.UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy(new NancyOptions
        {
            Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper(app)
        }));
    }
}
```

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    readonly IApplicationBuilder _app;

    public Bootstrapper(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        _app = app;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

        container.Register<IOptions<Endpoints>>(_app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<Endpoints>>());

        container.Register<IReservationService>(_app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IReservationService>());
    }
}
```

**wwwroot**

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>XXX</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="XXX">
    <link href="styles.61cc257ef8131303860b.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.f68c652d205feae6e02a.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.756a44edc7e0a68ce65c.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.940a3ce39a746f717f7b.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.d5f9dd82a3600822cae2.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that there is some problem with the handling of static content from the server but I can't seem to figure it out.

**How can I navigate around using the browser URL when hosting the Angular application in .NET Core?**

**Update 1:**

After adding:

```
PerformPassThrough = (context => context.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
```

the 404 error message goes away but page is now blank without any error message except the 404 in the console..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Modified Startup.cs
2. Added module that returns index.html for all requests.
3. Configured root path in bootstrapper.cs.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //For serving index.html on baseurl - this can we done in AppNancyModule aswell: Get("/", _ => View["index"]);
    app.UseDefaultFiles();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    loggerFactory.AddNLog();

    app.AddNLogWeb();

    app.UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy(new NancyOptions
    {
        Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper(app, env)
    }));
}
```

**AppNancyModule**

```
public class AppNancyModule : NancyModule
{
    public AppNancyModule()
    {
        //Get("/", _ => View["index"]);

        Get(@"^(.*)$", _ => View["index"]);
    }
}
```

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
public class AppRootPathProvider : IRootPathProvider
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    public AppRootPathProvider(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }
    public string GetRootPath()
    {
        return _environment.WebRootPath;
    }
}

public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    readonly IApplicationBuilder _app;

    protected override IRootPathProvider RootPathProvider { get; }

    public Bootstrapper(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        RootPathProvider = new AppRootPathProvider(environment);
        _app = app;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

        container.Register<IOptions<Endpoints>>(_app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<Endpoints>>());

        container.Register<IReservationService>(_app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IReservationService>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO the middleware you wrote should be after the app.UseDefaultFiles(); and app.UseStaticFiles();
And you are only handling API requests. Try to rewrite it a little bit to also handle 404 errors and to not handle requests with extensions:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404
        && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value)
        && !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
        await next();
    }
});
```

Comment: No success, still 404

Comment: To bad. That's the way, how it works for me: http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2016/04/04/aspnetcore-and-angular2-part1.html 
Maybe it's because of some NancyFX config, I never worked with it.

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if you have objections :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the first `await next();`. That's sending the request to `/reservations` down the pipeline, *before* rewriting the URL to `index.html`.

When it hits Nancy, it'll see if it can handle `/reservations`, which it can't, and render a 404 page.

Comment: No success, still bank page. In addition, it gives console error: TypeError: error.json is not a function

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if you have objections :) Thanks